# Google column chart - column values don't match axis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a column chart as follows:

[image]

I've added the values of the data, and as you can see the columns don't make sense in relation to the Y axis - why is this?

The chart options:

```
var options = {
    title: 'Task Estimates',
    backgroundColor: { fill: 'transparent' },
    chartArea: { width: '50%' },
    height: '400px',
    hAxis: { direction: -1, slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 45, title: 'Tasks' },
};

var url = "http://theurl";

$.getJSON(url, function (jsonChartData) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonChartData);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chartHtmlElement);
    chart.draw(data, options);

});
```

The json is:

```
{
    "cols":[
        { "id":"A", "label":"Task", "type":"string", "role":null },
        { "id":"B", "label":"Days Estimated", "type":"number", "role":null },
        { "id":"C", "label":"Days Actual", "type":"number", "role":null }
    ],
    "rows":[
        { "c":[ { "v":"Task 3" }, { "v":"7" }, { "v":"4" } ] },
        { "c":[ { "v":"Task 1" }, { "v":"10" }, { "v":"24" } ] },
        { "c":[ { "v":"Task 2" }, { "v":"100" }, { "v":"0" } ] }
    ],
    "p":null
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something else I need to specify to make the axis work correctly?

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/6K3Wc/1/

Comment: heres an alternative way to express the data and it works -http://jsfiddle.net/C7Trr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are entering your numbers as strings, when they should be entered as numbers:

```
{
    "cols":[
        {
            "id":"A",
            "label":"Task",
            "type":"string",
            "role":null
        },
        {
            "id":"B",
            "label":"Days Estimated",
            "type":"number",
            "role":null
        },
        {
            "id":"C",
            "label":"Days Actual",
            "type":"number",
            "role":null
        }
    ],
    "rows":[
        {
            "c":[
                {
                    "v":"Task 3"
                },
                {
                    "v":7
                },
                {
                    "v":4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "c":[
                {
                    "v":"Task 1"
                },
                {
                    "v":10
                },
                {
                    "v":24
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "c":[
                {
                    "v":"Task 2"
                },
                {
                    "v":100
                },
                {
                    "v":0
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "p":null
}
```

Comment: Argh, what a schmuck. I knew it had to be something stupid when I couldn't find anything on google. Thanks!